# Set up cross account access for AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-data-pipeline

I have two AWS accounts, say A (for use of AWS services) and B(for s3). I want to access B's s3 bucket in account A's Data pipeline service to manage data transfer within Account B. I have access key pair for Account B. How can I set up S3 access to data pipeline service using access key pair?

Comment: You can add policy to the user's B's s3 bucket.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Data Pipeline, but I suspect you will need to:

- Add a **Bucket Policy** to the Amazon S3 bucket in Account-B that permits access from the IAM Role being used by Data Pipeline in Account-A
- Add permissions to the **IAM Role** being used in Data Pipeline in Account-A so that it is permitted to access the bucket in Account-B (or granting permission for all buckets will work too)

The permissions need to be granted in both directions.

I suspect that this is more likely to work than giving Data Pipeline a special set of credentials to use when accessing that particular bucket.

Comment: Agree. Similarly to how you copy s3 data from one account to another. The following article can be checked to get an example of the bucket policy that should be configured:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/copy-s3-objects-account/